# Configuration Error , Finding assembly after I swapped referenced dll out. Visual Studio 2003

Tags: asp.net, configuration

Here is the situation. I had a clean build of my asp.net web application working. I then went into the bin folder under the web app and replaced two referenced dll's with two older version of the same dll's. (Same name etc.)  After testing I replaced those dll's back to the new ones and now my application keeps throwing the configuration error

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = xxxxx.xxxx.Personalization
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/inetpub/wwwroot/appname
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = bin

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).

I found this issue on the web and tried all the solutions to it but nothing worked. I then went into all my projects that it references under the solution and cleared out the bin/debug folder in each, I cleared out the obj folder under each and also deleted the temporary files associated with the application. I rebuilt it and it still will not work due to this error

Not sure what is causing this or how to fix this issue. I have tried restarting IIS, stopping index services which was said to be a known issue. This is .net framework 1.1 app and visual studio 2003

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a shadow copy issue... Try clearing the ASP.NET temporary file directory and let it get recreated.